# Добавление альфа-канала к RGB изображению

Tags: python, opencv

Использую opencv3.4 и python3.5

Запускаю пример

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('img.png')

b_channel, g_channel, r_channel = cv2.split(img)

alpha_channel = np.ones(b_channel.shape, dtype=b_channel.dtype) * 50 

img = cv2.merge((b_channel, g_channel, r_channel, alpha_channel ))

cv2.imwrite("test.png", img)
```

В итоге получается:

[image]

Как мне сделать так чтобы оставить исходное изображение без визуальных изменений?

оригинал:

[image]

Comment: т.е. вы хотите добавить прозрачный альфа канал?

Comment: Я как-то не представляю, как это возможно сделать. Не покажете какую-нибудь картинку с альфа-каналом примерно как вам надо?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611685/set-the-background-color-for-a-png-with-transparency

Comment: @MaxU Да, мне нужно добавить прозрачный альфа-канал